# HTML Horizontal Line HR

Tags: html

I created an hr line but when I view it on other browsers, the color I set for it doesn't retain and it defaults to a grey color. Is there another code I could use to create a line? I also need to create two lines to be stacked on top of each other. Thanks!

Here's the code!

```
     <tr>
          <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 30px 0 0; font-family: Century gothic; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; mso-height-rule: exactly; color: #4F2C1D"><span style="font-size: 40px;">FIRSTNAME LASTNAME</span><br><span style="font-size: 20px; color: #4F2C1D">(415) 333-3333<br>john.doe@gmail.com</span>
                  <br><br><hr width="60%" size="8" align="center" color="B7DD79"><br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: "when I view it on other browsers" — What other browsers? It sounds like *some unnamed browser* does what you want and *some other unnamed browser* does not. You need to give a clear problem statement.

Comment: "the color I set for it" — How did you set this colour? We can't tell what is wrong with your code if we can't see it. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`<hr>` layout attributes are removed in HTML5, possibly the browser it's "working" on allows you to use the outdated version.  Try using a CSS file to style it instead.

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer with no code provided.

Firstly try adding

```
hr {
    clear: both;
}
```

to the css to clear floating elements.

Secondly you could always make an empty div with a border bottom which should work?

Comment: What browser is it not working on? Seems to be working on Chrome, IE and Edge for me.

Comment: I believe the color attribute requires a # symbol?